# Best way to initialize datastore w/ related entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

To run my app, I need some static entities,

so I've decided to upload them w/ bulkloader through [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) from CSV files.

But I have some entities those have relationship in between.
Like:

```
- kind: Category
  properties:
  - name: name

- kind: SubCategory
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: parent_id
  - name: name
```

How should I create a csv data to make it?
Is there any other way that I should take to init my app datastore?

Comment: Is your question about how to populate `parent_id`?

Comment: Yes. I want to have same parent_id in any env if I to use it to join 2 schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the key values (as strings) then you can create csv files with those values.  One file would contain the Category values `category_key,name`. The other file would contain the SubCategory values `subcategory_key,category_key,name`.  For example,

```
cat1,Category 1
cat2,Category 2

subcat1,cat1,SubCategory 1
subcat2,cat1,SubCategory 2
subcat3,cat2,SubCategory 3
```

You can read the files line by line, and create the static entities from the data like this (in Python):

```
import csv

with open('categories.csv') as csvfile:
    categories = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in categories:
        Category.get_or_insert(row[0], name=row[1])

with open('subcategories.csv') as csvfile:
    subcategories = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in subcategories:
        SubCategory.get_or_insert(row[0], parent_id=ndb.Key(Category, row[1]), name=row[2])
```

The `parent_id` value is constructed as a key.  Both loops use the [get_or_insert()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert) function to prevent duplicate values so you can run it multiple times.

I see that SubCategory has an ancestor, so you could replace the last call with this (and remove the `parent_id` attribute):

```
        SubCategory.get_or_insert(row[0], parent=ndb.Key(Category, row[1]), name=row[2])
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was thinking to pair them on get w/ merge join, but this way - insert parent key in SubCategory in advance looks more simple and less cost....

Comment: It's important to remember that BigTable is not a relational database, it's more like a NoSQL database.  There are no schemas, constraints on keys or joins.